# How to put a selection listener on an EditText in a SearchView?

Tags: java, android

I've looked about how to do it on a TextView: you have to subclass it and override `onSelectionChanged`. The `SearchView` can be subclassed as well, but I don't want to clone one just for this.

So, is there another way for that?